# Get access to application layout from Android Phonegap Plugin

Tags: java, android, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I'm currently writing a plugin that is attempting to add a view to the current LinearLayout of my application.

Though I am struggling to get access to the linear layout from within a plugin, I can add the view fine if I do so within my main activity as so:

```
MyView view = new MyView(this);
root.addView(myView);
```

But to get the root LinearLayout in my plugin I have assumed that:

```
this.cordova.getActivity();
```

is my main activity and have been trying to cast it to the type of my main activity and call a function I added that will return the root LinearLayout object as so:

```
MyActivity myAct = (MyActivity)this.cordova.getActivity();

MyView view = new MyView(myAct);
myAct .GetLinearLayout().addView(view);
```

Though this doesn't seem to work and I receive no errors or such to help figure out why?

Anyone know how I can get access to the layout to add my view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay so I solved this slightly differently to what I was attempting to do above.

Firstly casting the activity returned by cordova:

```
MyActivity myAct = (MyActivity)this.cordova.getActivity();
```

Does actually work and returns the instance of your main activity, so that wasn't the problem.

In the end I couldn't figure out why adding another view to the root cordova layout from the main activity worked but not when I did so in a plugin so what I did was to create my view from within the activities onCreate() then I provided an accessor to the view class back to my plugin and worked on from there.

Comment: can you please publish here you solution i am trying to implement that issue and still it does'nt work

Answer (score 0):

The layout no longer exists after `init()` completes. The last thing that happens in `init()` is `setContentView()` is called with the layout. When `setContentView()` is called with a layout, the layout is inflated and the individual views in the layout are added to the activity.